# Can Jasmine climb up smooth vertical rectangular-cross-section planks?

Tags: climbers

Can jasmine climb up smooth, vertical, rectangular-cross-section planks? The planks will be made of the material HPL (high-pressure laminate). You can see a picture below to get an idea of how it looks. **In our case the planks will be 2 inches wide and have 1 inch space between them; there will also be space between the planks and the brick wall behind them.**

Will jasmine be able to climb? Will other climbing plants?

[image]

Comment: @gtz Welcome to the gardening site!  I'd love to see a self-answer some day with what you end up doing to the wall.

Comment: @YosefBaskin no answers in comments, please!

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine does't have sticky roots like ivy or specialised shoots like peas to hold a nearby object.

Jasmine always needs an external help to keep them straight. If you want to cover your whole wooden wall then you need to use multiple ropes to help them climb.

Jasmine will twist around the rope and with its help it can climb but if it can't then you will need to tie the stem of the pant and keep it straight.

Comment: I've been wondering, if you were very hands on with training until the first wrap or two grew around the planks, do you think it could climb then?  I've seen jasmine climb tree trunks, but those aren't as smooth.